# TDD document error: Test if element was added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, jasmine

How can I test if a canvas element is added to the DOM?

I have a Jasmine test script which uses jsdom to create the DOM and to test if a canvas element was added.

In the library file, I have the prototype function to add the element to the DOM.

I get an error ***ReferenceError: document is not defined*** from Jasmine that points to the CustomLibrary.prototype.create function.

Are there any alternatives to test this?

Jasmine test.js file:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var CustomLibrary = require('../lib/custom.js');

describe('Custom Library', function () {
    'use strict';

    var document;

    beforeEach(function (done) {

        jsdom.env({
            html: '<html><body><div id="someid"></div></body></html>',
            done: function (err, window) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                document = window.document;
                done();
            }
    });

    describe('Create', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            var custom = new CustomLibrary();
            custom.create();
        });

        it('should create a canvas element inside of container', function () {
            var canvasElements = document.getElementById('someid').getElementsByTagName('canvas');
            expect(canvasElements.length).toEqual(1);
        });
    });


});
```

Custom library file:

```
var CustomLibrary = (function () {

    function CustomLibrary() {
        this.create();
    }

    CustomLibrary.prototype.create = function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('someid');
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        element.appendChild(canvas);
    };

    return CustomLibrary;
})();


if ( typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.hasOwnProperty('exports') )
{
    module.exports = CustomLibrary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the

```
var document;
```

from the Jasmine test file.